# How to update Many-to-Many table with View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a method that should update the many-to-many table based on checkbox ticks. The many-to-many relationship here is between the `Exam` entity and the `Objectives` entity. However I don't know how to implement it.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,Date,TotalMarks,ObjList")] ViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var selectedObj = viewModel.ObjList.Where(o => o.isAssigned == true);

        var exam = new Exam()
        {
            id = viewModel.id,
            ExamDate = viewModel.Date,
            TotalMarks = viewModel.TotalMarks,
        };

        if(selectedObj == null)
        {
            exam.Objectives = new List<Objectives>();
        }

        //how do i implement this here?
        //exam.Objectives.Add(obj) 

        db.Entry(exam).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

As shown in the code, the update for the many-to-many table is based on the `ObjList` from the `View Model`. I referred to online tutorials that they use methods such as:

```
exam.Obj.Add(obj);

or

exam.Obj.Remove(obj);
```

However, I don't know how to implement this as those methods are passing the `model` itself into the `method`. My case here is to pass the `viewmodel` to the method so I have to create a `exam` variable before saving to `db`.

So, how do I update the many-to-many table?

Comment: `db.Exams.Add(exam);` `db.Exams.Remove(exam);`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the ObjList viewmodel to your `Objective` model and then add to context.

```
 var objectives= selectedOb.
       .Select(obj=> new Objective 
        {
             //map properties here like Id = obj.Id
        });
  exam.Objectives.AddRange(objectives);
```